# How to break out of loop if the condition is false?

Tags: python, inheritance, while-loop

In my program I want to output all numbers that are less than 10000 (for example, if I multiply the number 154 by 2, it should only return the values that are less than 10000). In my program, however, I still get a value back that is greater than 10000. Can someone help me?

here is my program:

```
import statistics

def verdoppeln(zahl):
    liste = []
    if zahl > 10000:
            print("Zahl nicht gültig.")
    else:
        print(zahl)
        while zahl < 10000:
            print(zahl * 2)
            zahl_neu = zahl * 2
            liste.append(zahl_neu)
            zahl = zahl_neu
            if zahl > 10000:
                print("Zur Kontrolle: Summe = ", sum(liste), "Anzahl: ", len(liste))
                print("Mittelwert: ", statistics.mean(liste))
        

verdoppeln(154)
```

Comment: You only check whether ``zahl`` satisfies the condition, yet you append ``zahl_neu``.

Comment: yeah i know, but how can i change it, so that it checks the value of zahl_neu?

Comment: You are already know how to check ``zahl``, in fact you are doing it twice. What problem do you have checking ``zahl_neu`` instead?

Comment: Did you mean: `while zahl < 5000:`?

Comment: In my case I want to print out all numbers and multiply them by 2, but if one of these numbers get rather than 10000, the program should stop this process and go to the next loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative without break:

```
import statistics

def verdoppeln(zahl):
    liste = []
    if zahl > 10000:
            print("Zahl nicht gultig.")
    else:
        print(zahl)
        zahl *= 2
        while zahl < 10000:
            print(zahl)
            liste.append(zahl)
            zahl *= 2            
        print("Zur Kontrolle: Summe = ", sum(liste), "Anzahl: ", len(liste))
        print("Mittelwert: ", statistics.mean(liste))
        
verdoppeln(154)
```

Comment: Anything higher then `4999` will throw an error for `statistics.mean()`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `while`-check is only done at the start of each loop. So if `zahl` is bigger then `10000` after `zahl * 2`, it will still be printed and added to `liste`. If you change your `while` termination condition to `True` and break the while loop from the inside with the `break`-statement when the value of `zahl` becomes greater then `10000`, you should get your desired result.

Also, the use of `zahl_neu` is not needed, you can use `zahl` only and that will work fine.

Try this:

```py
import statistics

def verdoppeln(zahl):
    liste = []
    if zahl > 10000:
            print("Zahl nicht gültig.")
    else:
        print(zahl)
        while True: # Changed the termination condition to True, in other words, never stop
            zahl *= 2
            if (zahl >= 10000): # Added termination condition from inside the loop
                break
            print(zahl)
            liste.append(zahl)
        print("Zur Kontrolle: Summe = ", sum(liste), "Anzahl: ", len(liste))
        if (len(liste) >= 1): # statistics.mean need liste to have at least one element
            print("Mittelwert: ", statistics.mean(liste))
        
verdoppeln(154)
```

This will output:

```
154
308
616
1232
2464
4928
9856
Zur Kontrolle: Summe =  19404 Anzahl:  6
Mittelwert:  3234
```

Comment: Surely `verdoppeln(5000)` fails the requirements from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your limits:

```py
import statistics

def verdoppeln(zahl):
    liste = []
    if zahl >= 5000:
            print("Zahl nicht gültig.")
    else:
        print(zahl)
        while zahl < 5000:
            zahl *= 2
            print(zahl)
            liste.append(zahl)
        print("Zur Kontrolle: Summe = ", sum(liste), "Anzahl: ", len(liste))
        print("Mittelwert: ", statistics.mean(liste))
        

verdoppeln(154)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def verdoppeln(zahl):
    liste = []
    if zahl > 10000:
        print("Zahl nicht gültig.")
    else:
        while zahl < 10000:
            print(zahl)
            zahl = zahl * 2
            if zahl > 10000:
                print("Zur Kontrolle: Summe = ", sum(liste), "Anzahl: ", len(liste))
                print("Mittelwert: ", statistics.mean(liste))
            else:
                liste.append(zahl)
```